# HTML Box on Bing Map not able to view properly in IE8 or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, bing-maps, ie8-compatibility-mode

This Bing Outage Map, is not letting me view the html box on pin properly.
I can only view full text of the box in IE in compatible view.

Comment: What doctype are you specifying in the HTML page?  This usually affects how DOM elements are rendered in IE.  I've had issues with that in the past.

Comment: @Craig Can you please tell me where can I find that info you asked for?

Comment: Right click, View source.  Right at the top of the HTML page will be something like `<!DOCTYPE ...!>`

Comment: Please post a fiddle of the current code so that we can figure out the actual reason of the problem. IE is always a unique package each version carry different ways we need to deal.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify minimum cross compatibility lines

Doctype in the top of html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

also under `head` tag please define this `meta` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contant="IE=edge" />
```

This should tweak some of the problems,

if not please reply with link of page or some live working code and its fiddle, that will help better :)

Comment: Hey, Thanks I will try this out. the page is public so here it is. http://goo.gl/5oQ1kp, I am trying to make app out of this so I needed help on this part.

Comment: Although it seems layer issue, here in IE8 it tweaks issues by changing this meta. try and reply if not working will see another option :)

Comment: I just learned that the html is over written by another software  after few minutes.

Comment: Ok in that case insert your code after that again, or call the function after few minutes again :)

Comment: I will check and reply, running busy so will take some time.

Comment: I was checking the script, in IE8 and IE9 gives me error while  attaching "onmouseup" event..(in the scripts you are adding using .asmx file) also Meta Tag must be self closing, you have not added the same in your link's page; Add it same as-in the answer above, you have to change that part. and 'Doctype transitional' is a good thing. let me know after changing the meta accurately, as in IE we can not assume it will correct on its own :(

Comment: I will like to add that it is working fine in IE 11 and the PIN List is not published in page(drop down is not getting filled).